# Can I use both preload and modulepreload to maximise browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules, preload

I want to preload and early parse my javascript module code in `my-module.js`. For that I use `link="modulepreload"` which does exactly that. But modulepreload wasn't introduced in Safari until just 3 weeks ago and I want to make sure those with Safari pre version 17 still has the fastest possible experience. Can I just throw in a `link="preload" as="script"` before or will there be side effects?

In `<head>`:

```
<link rel="modulepreload" href="my-module.js" />
```

my-module.js:

```
export default function () {
    // ...
}
```

Use of my-module.js inline:

```
<script type="module">
    import mm from "my-module.js";
    mm();
</script>
```

For the sake of the question, let's assume I do need to execute the module script later, like before `</body>` and not just execute directly in `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be: **No**

I tested using both `rel="preload"` and `rel="modulepreload"`. Different order did not make any difference.

Safari v17 has the behaviour I want - the resource is preloaded and only downloaded once.

Chrome v117 and Firefox v118 both downloads the resource twice. Not good. And they also double download if I only use `rel="preload"` for a module script (that I later import).

There is a [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1178198) on the double download when combining `rel="preload"` and module script. It says fixed, but it isn't (or it maybe it once was) and reading the discussion it seems like double download is according to spec.

I guess the solution is to only use `rel="modulepreload"` when using javascript modules. And to import important modules early.